# How to deal with warnings in pycharm like "Unexpected type(s):(ndarray[int]) Possible types:(int)(slice)"?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, warnings

When I typed the following code, a warning appears in the second line at 'f_ind' as the title.
What I know is that `dispenser.capacity` and `tracker.f_position` both return a list. More codes about the method are as following.

This is the first time I've asked a question here. Anyone can help me? Many thanks to you.

```
f_ind = np.argmax(np.array(dispenser.capacity))
c_ind = tracker.closest_cind(tracker.f_position[f_ind])

class Tracker:
    def __init__(self, fleet_position, customer_position):
        self.f_num = len(fleet_position)
        self.c_num = len(customer_position)
        self.reference_distance = _getNumpyArray(fleet_position, customer_position)
        self.f_position = [self.c_num] * self.f_num

    def closest_cind(self, p1):
        distance_exFleet = np.delete(self.reference_distance, self.c_num, 1)
        closest_array = np.argmax(distance_exFleet, axis=1)
        return closest_array[p1]

class Dispenser:
    def __init__(self, demand, capacity, q_c):
        self.capacity = capacity
```

Comment: The output of `argmax` can work as index to a numpy array, but isn't suitable for a list  Look at `f_ind`

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! The problem is settled.